# Как правильно?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

1. НЕ должным образом - здесь "не" с прилагательным слитно или раздельно?
2. В конце писем обычно пишут "С уважением(,) С.С.". Нужна ли эта запятая и почему
   Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если частица НЕ в сочетании с этими словами образует новое слово, которое называет определенное понятие, противоположному тому, которое выражается словом без частицы НЕ: неправда (ложь) недорогой (дешевый). Думаю что здесь слитно.

Answer (score 0):

1. В зависимости от контекста. Если вы подразумеваете, что работа выполнена не должным, а безобразным образом...то пишется отдельно!!!                                             2. Запятую обязательно ставим, т.к. обращение надо выделять на письме запятыми...